# Node js - Why 3 connection?

Tags: node.js, sockets, google-chrome, networking, tcp

Consider this small server for node.js

```
var net = require ('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

    console.log("Connection detected");

    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('server disconnected');
    });

    socket.write("Hello World");
    socket.end();
});

server.listen("8888");
```

When I test the server with Chrome on my Macbook Pro, I get three times the *"Connection detected"* message in the console.

I know one is for well connecting, another for the favicon, but what's the third one all about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested it with Firefox and `wget` (which is a Linux command line program), as well as `telnet` to do the *deep* investigation. Surprisingly, all of these don't make any extra connection (obviously they don't even try to download the favicon). So I fired up Wireshark and captured a session, and quickly discovered that Chorme systematically makes *useless* connection, ie it just [connects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) (`SYN`, `SYN-ACK`, `ACK`) and then closes the connection (`RST`, `ACK`) without sending anything.

Just a quick googlin and I found [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116982) (excerpt):

> I suspect the "empty" TCP connections are
>
> 1. backup TCP connections,
> 2. IPv4/IPv6 parallel connections, or
> 3. TCP pre-connections,
>
> A backup TCP connection is made only if the original TCP connection is
>   not set up within 250 milliseconds.  IPv4/IPv6 parallel connections
>   are made only if the server has both IPv6 and IPv6 addresses and the
>   IPv6 connection is not set up within 300 milliseconds.  Since you're
>   testing a local server at localhost:8080, you should be able to
>   connect to it quickly, so I suspect you are seeing TCP
>   pre-connections.
>
> To verify if the "empty" TCP connections are TCP pre-connections, open
>   the "wrench" menu > Settings > Under the Hood > Privacy, and clear the
>   "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" check box. 
>   Shut down and restart Chrome.  Are the "empty" TCP connections gone?

For further reference, see [the linked thread](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116982), which explains more in-depth what *backup, parallel and pre-connections* are and if/why this is a good optimization.